# Get link for taxonomy to show top-level terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

Is it possible to get a link for a taxonomy as such, not its individual terms? And to which page in the template hierarchy will this link point?

Consider a hierarchical taxonomy called 'products'. Top level terms are 'productgroup1', 'productgroup2' and 'productgroup3'. Now I can get the link of a term like 'productgroup1' (using `get_term_link`) and it will be something like http://localhost/products/productgroup1, which will point to `taxonomy-products.php`. On this page I will show child terms of the term 'productgroup1' in the taxonomy.

But I also need a page for showing all top-level terms. So I need a page with link http://localhost/products/ on which I will show those top-level terms 'productgroup1', 'productgroup2' and 'productgroup3'. Also, it would be nice if this link would point to the same template `taxonomy-products.php`, since most of the code will be the same.

But http://localhost/products/ gives a 404 and a function for getting a link for a taxonomy does not exist? I can only find a function for getting a term's link.

Comment: Sounds like you need a Custom Post Type called "product" with an archive at "example.com/products" and then you can apply your "productgroup" taxonomy to that CPT.

Comment: All archives are a collection of posts, there is no concept of an archive of terms in WordPress. If you just want to force the same template on multiple types of pages, there are [template filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) that let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Webelaine already answered your question.

You're working against yourself - just create a custom post type called product.

Note that custom post types can be hierarchial (like pages), if that's what you're after.

**EDIT**

Taking into consideration what the OP stated in the comments area, the best advice that I can offer is "create a custom page template" where you query all of the top level taxonomy terms.

The code for that would be:

```
$args = [
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_category',
  'parent'        => 0,
  'hide_empty'    => false           
];
$terms = get_terms( $args );
// loop through all terms
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
  // display only the term name
  echo '<h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>';
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I already have a custom post type 'product'. When creating a new product entry, the user can select a productgroup from the custom taxonomy to tell what kind of product this is. This is quite normal wordpress behaviour, that is what taxonomies are for, am I right? Using hierarchical custom post types means the hierarchical structure can be redefined with every new product posted, this is error prone. I want the taxonomy to be relatively stable, not to be changed easily or by mistake when entering a new product.

Comment: Ah, got confused when you said "Consider a hierarchical taxonomy called 'products'." A taxonomy would be "product tags" or "product category". Let me modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's the code that I use in taxonomy-products.php. As I understand you advise to make another file (a page template) to show the top-level terms in. The thing is, both files will contain roughly the same code, since both files will query the taxonomy to show the terms with the same html. I was hoping on a more elegant solution, I don't like to duplicate code. Of course I could place the code in another file and include it in both files, but I was hoping on a more elegant solution.

Comment: Well you could always include that code at the very top of the archives page of said post type. So you'd basically create archive-product.php (assuming "product" is your cpt). Then have that code at the very top to display only the taxonomies and then have the regular loop underneath that.